# Using Scons to run other build scripts "underneath"

Tags: bash, scons

I'm working on a contract to enhance a huge gnarly build system that's based on SCons but with a bunch of shell scripts and makefiles intertwined with it.

The system runs a bunch of individual SCons commands and the request from my client was to put in a "top level" SConscript to control some underlying SCons runs.

I got this to work by using the Command function:

```
tgt = env.Command('bogus.out', 'bogus.in', "./stc.sh")
```

where the shell script 'stc.sh' removes the next target's controlling fake file 'pkgbogus.out':

```
tgt2 = env.Command('pkgbogus.out', 'pkgbogus.in', "./stcpkg.sh")
```

This works fine, and I understand that this is completely out of scope for normal SCons use ... but is there also a slicker way to do this without these 'bogus' files?

Comment: Using a simple script (Python preferrably) instead of SCons? You already mentioned that this might be out of scope for a dependency tracking build system like SCons, and from what I read so far, I definitely agree. Serial invocation of several steps/stages is not what our users usually aim at. Question: Should stcpkg.sh always run, or only when some output from stc.sh changed?

Comment: The idea is that stcpkg.sh should not run unless stc.sh, and stc.sh removes the 'pkgbogus.out' file as part of its run.

Comment: So are they just arbitrarily trying to force the order of execution between these two scripts?  Or does the first script produce a file(s) needed by the second script?

Comment: Trying to speed things up; the dependencies are messed up in the main SCons setup so adding this top layer speeds it up a lot in the "incremental" case. I got it to work just by using 'env.Depends()' explicitly between individual targets; still dependent on the files but I renamed them away from 'bogus' ... **tgt** above is now using files starting with **stc**.